# Controller did not call the SignalR

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, signalr

I read a lot here on stackoverflow before post this, and the only that help, but not really, was

> [SignalR call from controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63721149/signalr-call-from-controller)

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

I thought that that error they say was my error, but didnt work. So When the client send a message, this should trigger the hub, but didnt... At least did show up
My controller is like...

```
//Constructor
        private readonly IHubContext<ChatHub> chatHub;
        public UserController(IHubContext<ChatHub> hubContext)
        {
            this.chatHub = hubContext;
        }

//Method
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Message(Message message)
{
            await chatHub.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message.emisor, message.Text);
}
```

Chat.js

```
"use strict";

var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chatHub").build();

//Disable send button until connection is established
document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = true;

connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (user, message) {
    var msg = message.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
    var encodedMsg = user + " says " + msg;
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = encodedMsg;
    document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);
});

connection.start().then(function () {
    document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = false;
}).catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});

document.getElementById("sendButton").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    var user = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    var message = document.getElementById("messageInput").value;
    connection.invoke("SendMessage", user, message).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

ChatHub class

```
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task SendMessage(string name, string message)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", name, message);
        }
    }
```

So, this method on chathub, did not have any reference, If I debug, didnt call this method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only call hub methods from the client. And you call client methods from the server.

`IHubContext` is on the server and all it does is send to clients. If you want to "call a hub method" from the server, then you need to refactor your code to have a common class that both the hub method calls and your controller calls.

Comment: Then... I need to call the SendMessage method from the controller??

Comment: No. If you have common logic that you want both a hub method and a controller to call, then you should place that logic in a class that both the hub and the controller use. For example:
`class DoSomething
{
    // called from Hub and from Controller
    public Task SendMessage(IHubContext<ChatHub> context)
    {
        // do something
    }
}`

Comment: So... In that way, when I call the class from the controller, it will be automatic instance the hub class right??